# Is this a memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have something similar to this.

```
initMyclass {
 if (self= [super init]) {
   classMember = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }
 return self;
}
```

Instruments reports a leak there.

I'm leaking memory there  ?
If not, xcode reports false memory leaks ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instruments is reporting the leak there because you're not releasing the object elsewhere.  You need to have `[classMember release]` in that class's `dealloc` method:

```
- (void) dealloc {
  [classMember release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I did, but instruments still reports a leak.

Comment: @José - perhaps your `myClass` object itself is never getting deallocated?

Comment: Then you are retaining it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you should use properties or explicit accessors.

If you had this:

```
@interface myObject : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *classMembers;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray *classMembers;

@end

@implementation myObject
@synthesize classMembers;

-(id) init{
    if (self=[super init]) {
        self.classMembers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    }
    return self;
}//-------------------------------------(id) init------------------------------------

-(void) dealloc{
    [classMembers release];
    [super dealloc];
}//-------------------------------------(void) dealloc------------------------------------

@end
```

You would not (and should not ever) have to miss around with the retention of a property. This eliminates all leaks and over-releasing of properties.

If the property's object leaks, then you know automatically it is being retained in another object other than the instance of the class containing the property.

Comment: This code will in fact leak. initWithCapacity: returns a retained object, which is then again retained when you set the property. You should either append autorelease when you create the array, or use [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1], which will return an autoreleased object.

Answer (score -2):

Is it a *class* or *instance* member? Show us the `@interface` for this class.

Also, `initMyClass` .. or something .. is not a proper init method. It's signature should be of the form:

```
- (id) init {
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
        someInstanceVariable = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Be more specific when you ask a question here.

Comment: @interface myClass : NSObject {
 NSMutableArray *classMember;
}

Comment: The code is incredibly short and simple, how can it be more specific ?!. I'm trying to understand WHY instruments considers it a memory leak, when it isn't.

Comment: @St3fan other than the missing `- (id)` before the method selector, his init method is perfectly fine.

Comment: `(self = [super init]) != nil` is redundant. When `self = [super init]` returns nil, the conditional will fail because nil==0;

Comment: @TechZen I don't care if it is redundant, it is a style I use. Just like I prefer (foo == NO) vs (!foo) or (foo == YES) vs (foo).